# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on callback

Tags: javascript

```
function submit() {
    console.log('Submit!');
}

function foo(callback, param) {

    console.log(callback);

    // ... //

    callback(param); // <-- Script fails here

}

<input type="button" onclick="foo(submit)">
```

Why isn't this working?

```
function submit() { [native code] } foo.js:241
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: `event` doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not getting that far. It's failing to call the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrinsic event attributes (like `onclick`) have weird scoping rules that I don't pretend to fully understand.

`submit` inside the attribute is the `submit` **property** of the form element to which the input belongs.

Either:

- Explicitly pass `window.submit`
- Rename the function to something else *or*
- Bind your event handler with JavaScript instead of HTML.

I'd go [the latter route](http://jsbin.com/vilonuki/1/edit?html,output) myself on general principles (taking the opportunity to stop using globals), and consider renaming the function anyway to minimise confusion.

```
<input type="button">
<script>
    // Scoping IIFE omitted from this simplified example
    var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    button.addEventListener("click", function () { foo(submit); });

    function submit // etc etc
</script>
```

Comment: This was it, naming the function submit caused the problem. What a freaking headache, thanks!

Comment: Doh! I *totally* missed the fact that Cody had his *own* function called `submit`. Ugh. Definitely change that name. :-)

Comment: *"I'd go the latter route myself."* And either don't make the function global, or call it something else. :-) *edit -* Ah, we were thinking along the same lines...